# Does C# application made in windows 7 will run in windows xp

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have made C# application of Loan Receive Management for my client in windows 7(x86) and using Microsoft visual studio 2010 (.NET Framework 4.0) and it works fine, but my client using windows XP now. So I am worry that my application will run completely fine in his OS (XP).
If it can produce any problem or difficulties, please tell me about it and also suggest effective way to solve that problem.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I'll go see your client and test directly if your application works on his computer. Oh, maybe I should let you do that.

Comment: As long as they have the proper version of .Net installed for your app (and you're not doing any OS specific interop calls) then it should work fine.

Comment: Make sure to compile it targeting X86 OS

Answer (score 2):

It should work fine, You should only be worried if your application is targeting .Net framework 4.5 which is not available on windows XP. To be on the safe side, select "Any CPU" for platform target in project properties.

Make sure that the target computer has .Net framework 4.0 installed.

Answer (score 1):

yes it should works fine you  need  sp3 installed on XP and compile your app in  32 bit mode  to be more sure   and make sure your .net installed as Full on XP. You can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718)